# In App Purchase with Apple hosted contenct, payment queue called after screen lock

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an app with in app purchases.
These in app purchases have apple hosted content associated with them.
So a user tap, buys and downloads the content. 
So far so good, everything works properly.

In order to have the downloads work properly I can't call before the download ends:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]]
```

My problem arises when the user locks and unlocks the device.

After the device is unlocked the paymentQueue gets called again with whatever is downloading which I ignore in code but the dialog box requesting the user's password arises again.
This is completely redundant since the download is still running in the background.
If I hit cancel nothing changes and the download proceeds to finish.
If I complete my password a new transaction is added to the queue, so the same file is now downloading twice.

If I close down the app and start up again, again the dialog for my password is shown, which if I ignore starts downloading properly. If I enter my password another product is queued.

I have made sure that there are no duplicate observers and have narrowed down the problem to not calling `finishTransaction`which I can't, since that cancels the download.

My code below:

```
+ (id)sharedSingleton {
    if ( !shared ) {
        shared = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:nil];
    }
    return shared;
}

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {
    if ( !shared ) {
        self = [super init];
        shared = self;
    } else {
        self = shared;
    }
    if ( self && productIdentifiers ) {
        _paused = false;
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)requestProducts {
    //if there is a new request cancel the old one
    if ( _productsRequest ) {
        [_productsRequest setDelegate:nil];
        [_productsRequest cancel];
        _productsRequest= nil;
    }
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    _productsRequest = nil;
    _products = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in response.products) {
        [_products setObject:skProduct forKey:skProduct.productIdentifier];
    }
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    _productsRequest = nil;
    if ( error ) {
        [self handleError:error];
    }
}

- (BOOL)checkIfProductPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [self getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:productIdentifier] != NOT_BOUGHT;
}


#pragma mark - Purchasing
- (void)buyProductWithInAppID:(NSString *)inAppId {
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectForKey:inAppId];
    if ( product ) {
        SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    } else {
        NSMutableDictionary *details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [details setValue:@"Can't reach Apple's servers. Please try again. If not connected to the internet, please connect and try again." forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"In App Error" code:200 userInfo:details];
        [self handleError:error];
        [self requestProducts];
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.downloads) {
        NSString *iap = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        int state = [self getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:iap];
        switch (state) {
            case NOT_BOUGHT:
            case BOUGHT:
                NSLog(@"start download after purchase: %@", iap);
                [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:iap restored:NO];
                [self setStateForUserDefaults:DOWNLOADING ForInAppID:iap];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                break;
            case DOWNLOADING:
                NSLog(@"downloading");
                //ignore
                break;
            case DOWNLOADED:
                NSLog(@"downloaded");
                //finish transaction
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self transactionFinished];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        [self transactionFinished];
    }
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    BOOL shouldRestore = false;
    for ( NSString *iap in _restoreInAppArray ) {
        if ( [transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:iap] ) {
            shouldRestore = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( (_restoreInAppArray != nil && shouldRestore) || _restoreInAppArray == nil ) {
        NSString *iap = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        int state = [self getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:iap];
        switch (state) {
            case NOT_BOUGHT:
            case BOUGHT:
                NSLog(@"start download after restore: %@", iap);
                [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:iap restored:YES];
                [self setStateForUserDefaults:DOWNLOADING ForInAppID:iap];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                break;
            case DOWNLOADING:
                //ignore
                break;
            case DOWNLOADED:
                //finish transaction
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self transactionFinished];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        [self transactionFinished];
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads {
    _activeDownloads = [downloads copy];
    for (SKDownload *download in downloads) {
        if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFinished) {
            [self processDownload:download];
            [self setStateForUserDefaults:DOWNLOADED ForInAppID:download.contentIdentifier];
            [queue finishTransaction:download.transaction];
            [self transactionFinished];
        } else if (download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateActive) {
            NSString *productID = download.contentIdentifier;
            NSTimeInterval remaining = download.timeRemaining;
            float progress = download.progress;
            //int mbs = round(download.contentLength/1024/1024);
            if ( delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadProgress:forInAppID:timeRemaining:totalMB:)] ) {
                [delegate downloadProgress:progress forInAppID:productID timeRemaining:remaining totalMB:0];
            }
        } else if ( download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFailed ) {
            if ( !_paused && [self getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:download.contentIdentifier] != DOWNLOADED) {
                NSLog(@"Download Failed %li: %@", (long)download.downloadState, download.contentIdentifier);
                [queue startDownloads:[NSArray arrayWithObject:download]];
            }
        } else if ( download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateWaiting || download.downloadState == SKDownloadStatePaused ) {
            if ( !_paused && [self getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:download.contentIdentifier] != DOWNLOADED) {
                NSLog(@"Download Wait or Paused %li: %@", (long)download.downloadState, download.contentIdentifier);
                [queue resumeDownloads:[NSArray arrayWithObject:download]];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            [self setStateForUserDefaults:BOUGHT ForInAppID:download.contentIdentifier];
            [queue finishTransaction:download.transaction];
        }
    }
}

- (void)pauseAllDownloads {
    NSLog(@"pauseAllDownloads");
    _paused = true;
    if ( _activeDownloads ) {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] pauseDownloads:_activeDownloads];
    }
}

- (void)startAllDownloads {
    NSLog(@"startAllDownloads");
    _paused = false;
    if ( _activeDownloads ) {
        for ( SKDownload *download in _activeDownloads ) {
            //NSLog(@"downloads: %@ state: %i", download.contentIdentifier, download.downloadState);
            if ( download.downloadState == SKDownloadStatePaused || download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateFailed ) {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] resumeDownloads:[NSArray arrayWithObject:download]];
            } else if ( download.downloadState == SKDownloadStateWaiting ) {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:[NSArray arrayWithObject:download]];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)processDownload:(SKDownload*)download {
    NSLog(@"processDownloads");
    // convert url to string, suitable for NSFileManager
    NSString *path = [download.contentURL path];

    // files are in Contents directory
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
    NSString *dir = [FileLocation getFolderToSaveWithDocumentDirectory:TRUE];

    for (NSString *file in files) {
        NSString *fullPathSrc = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        NSString *fullPathDst = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        // not allowed to overwrite files - remove destination file
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fullPathDst error:NULL];
        if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:fullPathSrc toPath:fullPathDst error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Error: unable to move item: %@", error);
        }
        [FileLocation setICloudFlagForFile:fullPathDst];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductDownloadComplete object:download.contentIdentifier];
}

- (void)cancelProductDownloadWithAppID:(NSString *)inAppId {
    for ( SKDownload *download in _activeDownloads ) {
        if ( [download.contentIdentifier isEqualToString:inAppId] ) {
            NSLog(@"Canceling: %@", inAppId);
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] cancelDownloads:[NSArray arrayWithObject:download]];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];
            [self transactionFinished];
        }
    }
}

- (void)restoreProductWithInAppIDArray:(NSArray *)inAppId {
    NSLog(@"restoreProductWithInAppIDArray: %@", inAppId);
    _restoreInAppArray = inAppId;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"failedTransaction");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchaseFailedNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
    if ( transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled ) {
        [self handleError:transaction.error];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    [self transactionFinished];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier restored:(BOOL)restored {
    if ( restored ) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductRestoredNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];
    }
}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    NSLog(@"restoreCompletedTransactions");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)transactionFinished {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductTransactionEnded object:nil userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)setStateForUserDefaults:(int)state ForInAppID:(NSString *)iap {
    NSLog(@"-setting state: %i %@", state, iap);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:state forKey:iap];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
+ (void)setStateForUserDefaults:(int)state ForInAppID:(NSString *)iap {
    NSLog(@"+setting state: %i %@", state, iap);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:state forKey:iap];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (int)getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:(NSString *)iap {
    return (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:iap];
}
+ (int)getStateFromUserDefaultsForInAppID:(NSString *)iap {
    return (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:iap];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc in app manager");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [_productsRequest cancel];
    _productsRequest.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: Can you add yourself as an observer for the application will resign active, and then call finish transaction there?

Comment: This would work but defeats the purpose of apple hosted downloads that run in the background... The only solution so far is prevent locking of the device and tell users not to exit the app.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and I am not been able to handle this thing. How did you handled this issue ?

Comment: I haven't really addressed it. I simply inform all users of the problem and tell them to wait for the download to finish.